# Upgrading old .NET 4.8 project to use Sharepoint online

Tags: .net, windows, sharepoint, office-interop

I have an old .NET 4.8 application that uses a mixture of Interop, System.IO functions, and some third party components to access files on a local server, plus some System.Diagnostics.Process.Start calls to open Office files from there.  I've been asked to look at what would need to be done so that they can switch to using Sharepoint Online (ie. the one hosted by Microsoft, not in-house) to store their files.  We will be using Windows Authentication - the Sharepoint user will be the Windows user who is logged in to the PC.

I've never done anything with Sharepoint before and I was hoping that I may be able to get away without too much work on this.  I don't suppose it is possible to use the Windows file system functions with a URL or something without making any major changes?

I'm guessing that I can probably do the Interop and Process.Start calls without major changes because Office should take care of it, but the other stuff is probably going to need me to use the Sharepoint API?

Even with the Process.Start calls though, I'm not sure how to do that - at the moment I'm just passing in the file path of the file and leaving it to Windows file associations to open the right Office file, but I imagine that won't work with a URL as it will probably just open the browser and download the file?

I've just also discovered Azure Files and I'm wondering if that might be a better solution for this.  Can anyone comment on that?